# List Column -Different Internal name for same List column Display Name

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I've noticed different Internal name for same List column in 2 different site collection .For example i've list column- *ParameterList Name* in Site Collection1  and i see internal name as *Parameter%5Fx0020%5FListName* for the same list column .But on Site collection 2 i see internal name as *ParameterList%5Fx0020%5FName* for the same List column.Same List exists in both site collection .
My client CAML query code breaks due to diference in Internal Name for the specified List column.I work in SP2010

Does any one have idea why this is happenning?

Answer (score 1):

These are not the same column. Check the ID.
It seems as they have been created using the UI and in Site Collection 1 they gave it the name "Parameter ListName" and then renamed it later. In site collection 2 they created a new column named "ParameterList Name".

If you want to preserve the items in the lists, then you can set the StaticName of the two columns to the same value and then in you code use [TryGetFieldByStaticName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcollection.trygetfieldbystaticname.aspx) to retrieve it.

Comment: Thanks for the response ,Just need to understand..how would i use Static name in CAML query ?

Comment: You can't but when you've looked up the field using static name, then you can use the ID or InternalName and insert into CAML